# Visual basic script not working on Outlook 2010 rule

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I've been trying to find a script that saves attachments to a folder on our network from Outlook. I've finally got something working but it looks like it doesn't work on my 2nd system which happens to be Outlook 2010. I can't say for sure if it's because of this difference.

**Code is:**

```
Sub SaveAllAttachments(objItem As MailItem)
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim strName, strLocation As String
    Dim dblCount, dblLoop As Double

    strLocation = "C:\test\"

    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    If objItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set objAttachments = objItem.Attachments
       dblCount = objAttachments.Count
       If dblCount <= 0 Then
           GoTo 100
       End If
       For dblLoop = 1 To dblCount
           strID = " from " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")           'Append the Date
           'strID = strID & " at " & Format(Time, "hh`mm AMPM") 'Append the Time
           ' These lines are going to retrieve the name of the
           ' attachment, attach the strID to it to insure it is
           ' a unique name, and then insure that the file
           ' extension is appended to the end of the file name.
           strName = objAttachments.Item(dblLoop).Filename 'Get attachment name
           strExt = Right$(strName, 4)                     'Store file Extension
           strName = Left$(strName, Len(strName) - 4)      'Remove file Extension
           strName = strName & strID & strExt              'Reattach Extension
           ' Tell the script where to save it and
           ' what to call it
           strName1 = strLocation & "PDF\" & strName                 'Put it all together
           strName2 = strLocation & "JPG\" & strName                 'Put it all together
           ' Save the attachment as a file.
           objAttachments.Item(dblLoop).SaveAsFile strName1
           objAttachments.Item(dblLoop).SaveAsFile strName2
        Next dblLoop
        objItem.Delete
    End If
100
ExitSub:
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `I've finally got something working` So above code already does what you want? How do you call the sub? I mean I don't think you can call it directly from the rule since it needs 1 argument *objItem*.

Comment: Comment out On Error GoTo ExitSub. If there is an error, which line? The method used for strExt, strExt = Right$(strName, 4), will not work for 4 character extensions.

Comment: @L42 the item being processed by the rule is objItem in the RunAScript code.

Comment: @niton Yeah, but it usually doesn't include the newest object item added. Or I may be wrong.

Comment: @L42 there is only one item to pass when a rule incudes RunAScript code. Sometimes coders ignore that item and instead incorrectly iterate through the inbox. The item has not yet reached the inbox so they think the code skipped the newest item.

Comment: @niton Ah learned something new I guess. I usually set up an event to do this. I didn't know the newest item is referenced automatically in the sub (passed in it) if set-up like above. I'll do some testing then.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what Outlook version you are using at the moment. The code should work correcly.

Possible reasons why it doesn't work:

1. I'd suggest choosing another location for saving files. The C: drive requires admin privileges on latest OS.
2. The rule is not triggered.
3. An error in the script. Try to call the script manually from other VBA sub and see what happens under the hood. Do you get any errors in the code?